# Why Safari search querys are added on google analytics

Tags: seo, google-analytics

On Google Analytics, we can track search queries.

`/illinois/weekly-claims/?back=https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&as qdr=all&as occt=any&safe=active&as q=How+do+you+answer+the+Illinois+state+PUA+certification+question&channel=aplab&source=a-app1&hl=en`

Please clarify what it is if anyone knows.